# BlockUI over just jQuery DatePicker during AJAX call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-blockui

I'm trying to use jQuery UI DatePicker with BlockUI during the onChangeMonthYear callback.  During the callback, I'm issuing an AJAX call to get a list of available dates for the month and I want to have BlockUI display a message over the Calendar while that request is completing.

I've seen many examples where developers are blocking the whole page but I haven't see a case where a developer is trying to just block out the calendar widget itself with a message.  When I try to call `$("#ui-datepicker-div").block()` nothing is presented over the calendar but if I simply do `$.blockUI({message: 'Test'});` it works as expected.

Here is my callback function:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/GetDaysForMonth",
        data: { 'Month': month },
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").block({message: "Loading..."});
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //set days on datepicker from result
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").unblock();
        }
    });
```

I would appreciate any insight around this behavior.

Thanks!